# Make pipeline job wait until previous is built

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How to make jenkins pipeline script programmatically wait until previous/last job execution is currently running or succeeded?

There is option to disable concurrent builds, but that is a really bad option that will stack commits.

Comment: Do you know the milestone step/plugin? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Milestone+Step+Plugin It might do what you need. Perhaps you can also use a "lock": https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/10/16/stage-lock-milestone/

Comment: Well yes and no. Actually the problem is with I guess Jenkins mechanism that strips queue if there are lets say 5 commiters it runs one build and puts all other commits in another build. Its unavoidable with quiet periods and disabling concurrency etc.